# What happens when both piping and input redirection is done on command

Tags: pipe, io-redirection

For command

```
echo 'from pipe'|(cat <<< 'from input redirect')
```

output is

```
from input redirect
```

What happens to the line 'from pipe' coming from echo?

Comment: It's probably discarded, as there can only be one standard input (at a time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be sitting unused in an output buffer and discarded when both commands have exited.

If the left hand side produces enough data to fill the output buffer, it will temporarily pause until the buffer has been consumed.  Since this won't happen here, it would eventually get a `SIGPIPE` signal and die from a "broken pipe" as soon as the right hand side command terminated.  It may also catch the `SIGPIPE` signal specifically and exit gracefully.