# Piping and input stream redirection to same command, which input does command take?

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I was trying to run the command given below

```
cat numbers.txt | sort < words.txt
```

The above command has a pipe from cat command feeding to input stream of sort command. But at the same time, input stream of the sort command is also redirected to the words.txt file. On running the command i found that the data from words.txt is sorted by the sort command and displayed back in terminal.

I don't understand how the shell processes the piping and redirection in such a case. Is it possible for one command to accept input stream from two different sources. My thoughts on how it worked internally was that, since redirection and piping are handled from left to right along the command, first the output stream of the cat command will be fed as the input stream for sort command. But since sort command is provided with another input stream redirection after this pipe, the input stream of sort command will be then be connected to words.txt. So when the command executes, data from words.txt would only reach sort command.

Also why isn't the following command not running.I have changed the redirection by overwriting to redirection by appending.

```
cat numbers.txt | sort << words.txt
```

There is a [**question**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/394848/what-happens-when-both-piping-and-input-redirection-is-done-on-command) partly similar to this, but i couldn't exactly understand how the pipe and redirection was handled by the shell.

Comment: While `>>` is "appending", `<<` means [here-document](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07_04).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redirections are processed from left to right, and [in Bash, after pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) (in fact, in [any POSIX shell](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_02)). In

```
cat numbers.txt | sort < words.txt
```

the shell first sets up `sort`’s (future) standard input to be the pipe from `cat`, but then when it processes `< words.txt`, changes it to read `words.txt`.

`<<` starts a heredoc:

```
cat numbers.txt | sort << words.txt
```

will sit waiting for a line saying “words.txt” (since that is specified as the end-of-input marker in your command). See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/86440)

Comment: @Vilinkameni but you were using it to prove “the command `cat` in the above examples will run completely, just its output will be discarded”, and it doesn’t.

Comment: What I (eventually, after a discussion which is now deleted, where you provided some counterexamples to my more general initial claim) wanted is to include the case if `command1` is a script. Generally, not all of the commands in it will be terminated in `command1 | command2 <somefile`. Under the effects of `set +o errexit`, only those commands from `command1` writing to stdout will be terminated due to receiving `SIGPIPE`.

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible for one command to accept input stream from two different sources.

No; an input stream is literally just a file descriptor that someone else hands to you. Just as you only have one file in a file, there's no way to merge multiple streams.

> ```
> cat numbers.txt | sort < words.txt
> ```

By the way, `cat` is short for con`cat`enate; its job literally is to concatenate all files specified on its command line to its output stream:

```
cat numbers.txt words.txt | sort
```

works. Of course, `sort` itself can also sort multiple files, so `sort numbers.txt words.txt` would work just as well.

But I guess the question is more general: 
If I have multiple files and stream, how do I concatenate them into one output?

Well, modern shells do have you covered (at least bash and zsh do):

```bash
cat file1 <(some program that generates output) <(echo "foo bar") file2 | sort
```

These shells have `<(…)`, i.e. "generate a temporary pipe that gets passed as input file name". Of course, there's also very simple subshell methods:

```bash
( cat file1; some program that generates output; echo "foo bar"; cat file2 ) | sort
```

has the same effect. (There *are* differences in the parallelism of execution; `cat <(sleep 2; echo hello) <(sleep 2; echo world)` takes 2 seconds to execute in total; `(sleep 2; echo hello; sleep 2; echo world)` takes 4 seconds.)

Comment: I actually did not want to concatenate the two files and feed them to sort. I used two files having different data so that i would understand which input stream was ultimately used by the sort command (pipe vs redirection). I guess I didn't phrase the question properly. My bad. But thank you for answer. I thought merging streams was something possible.

Comment: In POSIX sh, [FIFO](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/mkfifo.html)s can be used for a similar effect to `<()`, Instead of `sort <(prog1) <(prog2)` one would write `mkfifo prog1f prog2f; prog1 >prog1f & prog2 >prog2f & sort prog1f prog2f; rm prog1f prog2f`